# How to do localization in smali files?

Tags: android, localization, translation, smali

I have an app on forein language and I want to traslete it fully for example in the smali file I have this programming code:

`const-string v1, "Hello"`

How I can add reference to the string.xml file from this smali code?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it in com.xxx.yyy.HomeActivity, and your localized string'id in R.java is 0x7f050000.  Use the code below to replace the code `const-string v1, "Hello"`

```
invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/xxx/yyy/HomeActivity;->getResources()Landroid/content/res/Resources;

move-result-object v2

const/high16 v3, 0x7f050000

invoke-virtual {v2, v3}, Landroid/content/res/Resources;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1
```