# make const-string get string from strings.xml

Tags: smali

I want make the const-string get's strings from the resourcs/strings.xml

For example my package name is:

```
com.zz.lolo
```

the code string in smali file are:

```
const-string v1, "Hello"
```

I can't explain more than that, but sorry for that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38565350/how-to-do-localization-in-smali-files

Comment: The, question smiller to above!